# Constrain text fields so that they have even space between them and fill the whole screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm building an app that is supposed to be able to run on just about any iOS device that is running iOS8+. The issue is that means I have to support many different screen sizes. This is easy for `UITableView`s, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work for my signup view. Here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Pretty basic stuff; I essentially just have an "add photo" button that is constrained to the top layout guide, a bunch of textfields underneath it, and a "sign up" button that is constrained to the bottom layout guide. What I want to do is have all of the text fields be distributed evenly from the "add photo button" to the "sign up" button, in order to maximize my use of the screen space. As in: I want all of the text fields to be centered horizontally, and have even space between them.

The tough part is that the space is unspecified, because it will be different depending on the size of the device.

Is there a way to do this? Some sort of rule that tells the text fields to maintain an even space between their top and bottom neighbor? The best I can do for now is I have constrained all of the text fields to the "add photo" button at a fixed distance, and constrained the "sign up" button to the bottom, such that with larger screens I will have most of the content clustered at the top and the "sign up" button at the bottom, and for the smallest screen (iPhone 4/4S), the content looks evenly distributed (as it should be), because the "sign up" button is pushed up and the whole cluster of objects at the top is pushed down. Obviously this isn't a very ideal solution though.

I'd prefer to set this up via storyboard, but having to do it in code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to create these spaces is adding transparent views between your textfields. These transparent views will have a constraint 0 (top and bottom) to the textfield and your UIImageView and SignUp button. When you have all these transparent views created and located between your textfields you need to choose all of them (transparent views) and add the constraint "Equal Heights". Now the space between all your elements will be the same in all screens.

You can find more info in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8

Comment: Interesting... seems like a non-standard approach... but it worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: It's the Apple's solution for your question. Definitely they should do it more clean.

Comment: Yeah I read through that link. That's exactly it, though, you'd think Apple would've implemented a cleaner way to do it. I'm not complaining though :)